# Security with HTTPS and SSL

Tags: android, ssl-certificate

I have developed an android app where I am accessing one server url to access one xml file.In that server we have deployed one SelfSigned SSL Server Certificate.
I tried this code

// My Code:
            My Code is here as follows

```
        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        InputStream caInput = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server2); //server2 is the server2.crt Certificate file
        Certificate ca;
        try {
            ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
            System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
        } finally {
            caInput.close();
        }

        // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

        // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);

        // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

        // Tell the URLConnection to use a SocketFactory from our SSLContext
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection =
                (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
```

But I am getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed" Error.PLease help me how to access that URL?

Comment: you don't need to do any thing for that, not even SelfSigned SSL Server Certificate.check you app url here https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and check your Certification Paths and 
Protocols to enable,chipher suites,
Handshake Simulation.

Comment: But since the Server has a certificate configured how can the app access it without any client certificate?

Comment: if app work in post man without add any ssl certificate android also can work.

Comment: In that case will it be HTTPS?

Comment: it also work with https if you properly  chain your certificate in server side and enable required protocols for android and web.